# Where to find screenshots

Tags: transport-fever

I've found that pressing [F12](https://www.reddit.com/r/TransportFever/comments/5njqom/how_do_i_take_screen_shots_in_this_game/) will produce a popup "Screenshot Saved", but it's not copied to memory and I cannot find a saved file. I haven't found a screenshot save file location in the settings either. When pressing print screen, it just produces a screenshot of the startup splash screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key for taking screenshots is F12 when you play through Steam.

If you are, **the pictures are in your Steam folder**. The default location would be

> *C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\userdata\xxx\760\remote\446800\screenshots*

where '*xxx*' is your user's unique numerical ID, and '*446800*' is the unique ID of Transport Fever.

Alternatively, you can find them through Steam, by navigating to '*Content*', under your profile name:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

it should be in picture folders or the windows menu if you have windows 10(I don't know what version you have)(I also don't know if you have windows sorry if i'm no help)

Comment: I do have Windows 10, but there's no Transport Fever folder in the pictures folder or any such screenshots in other folders.

Comment: Steam allows access to the location in the game properties.
It's unfindable, two of the folders it's nested in only have a number as their name.